# CSS 2 Sass: How do I change the output format of the generated SCSS?

Tags: css, ruby, sass

I want to convert CSS to SCSS that looks like this:

```
.top {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  nav {
    background: #333;
  }
  ul {
    padding: 0;
    display: table-row;
  }
  li {
    display: table-cell;
  }
}
```

Instead, I am getting this:

```
.top {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  nav {
    background: #333; }
  ul {
    padding: 0;
    display: table-row; }
  li {
    display: table-cell; } }
```

How do I change the output indentation in the command:

```
sass-convert public/stylesheets/application.css public/stylesheets/application.scss
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs (and checking 'sass-convert -h' on the command line) there is no way to change the output style when going from css to scss (or sass).

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem so I used the following Python to do some post-processing and fix up the generated output to the `:expanded` [output style](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style):

```
import sys
    import re

path = sys.argv[1]

scss = open(path).read()

# Fix up the indentation of closing braces to use a :expanded rather than :nested style.
scss = re.sub(r'\t(\t*)([^\}\n]*;) (\}.*)', r'\t\1\2\n\1\3', scss)
for i in range(0, 10):
    # This line is executed multiple times to fix up multiple closing braces on a single line.
    scss = re.sub(r'\t(\t*)\};? \}', r'\t\1}\n\1}', scss)

open(path, 'w').write(scss)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using this tool http://css2sass.heroku.com/

I have used this to convert CSS into SCSS